# How to separate the final part of the text in Java?

Tags: java, split, substring

I have this text for example

xxxyyy zzzzzz.xxxxxxxxy xyxyzzdxy xxxxx.yyyzyzzz.september/17/2014

I want to separate the date (september/17/2014) that is in the end of the text after final "."
and then put this date in another line

in the end I want something like this.

xxxyyy zzzzzz.xxxxxxxxy xyxyzzdxy xxxxx.yyyzyzzz.

september/17/2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
String s = "your.string.date";
String d = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
String r = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("."));
```

`d` will contain the date and `r` the rest of the string.

Print it however you like :

```
System.out.print(r + "\n" + d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = "xxxyyy zzzzzz.xxxxxxxxy xyxyzzdxy xxxxx.yyyzyzzz.september/17/2014";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this

```
String str = "xxxyyy zzzzzz.xxxxxxxxy xyxyzzdxy xxxxx.yyyzyzzz.september/17/2014"

String firstString = str.split("\\.")[0]; //xxxyyy zzzzzz.xxxxxxxxy xyxyzzdxy xxxxx.yyyzyzzz
String secondString = str.split("\\.")[1]; //september/17/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `lastIndexOf()`

[Java strings tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_lastindexof.htm)

Let's assume your desired text is stored in `my_string`, then you'd do something like:

```
int last_idx = my_string.lastIndexOf('.');
String date_substring = my_string.substring(last_idx + 1);
```